# How to get onclick event for jQuery Chosen drodpown listbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Hi I am developing one jquery application. I ghave one dropdownbox with jquery choosen.

```
$(function () {
        $(".limitedNumbSelect").chosen();
    });
```

This is my dropdown and binding values from database.

```
 <b>Awarded To:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:ListBox ID="ddlvendorss" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" class="limitedNumbSelect"></asp:ListBox>
```

I am trying to get click event for the above dropdown. As soon as i click on the dropodwn i want to fire a alert before loading any options.

```
 $('#ddlvendorss').click(function (e) {
            alert("I am going crazy");

        });
```

In the below code checkedValues arrays contains some values(values present in dropdownlistbox). As soon as i click on the drodpown i ant to hide those values. But below code doesnt work.

```
 $(".chzn-select").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function () {
        $(".limitedNumbSelect option").each(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var display = checkedValues.indexOf(val) === -1;
            $(this).toggle(display);
            $('.limitedNumbSelect option[value=' + display + ']').hide();
            $(".limitedNumbSelect").find('option:contains(' + display + ')').remove().end().chosen();

        });
    });
```

Above code does not work. May I get some advise on this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Chosen hides the `select` thus you are not actually clicking the element.

Comment: Actually i am trying to hide some of the options in dropdownboxlist. I have one gridview with checkbox. As soon as i check any row in gridview corresponding value in dropdown i want to hide. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Please update your question with the fiddle link. Thanks

Comment: Use events from the plugin api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chosen hides the `select` element, thus you are not actually clicking the element. However you can use `chosen:showing_dropdown` event

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
  alert('No need to go crazy');;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/n39fcehh/)

If you want to hide options, You can use

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function() {
    //Find options and hide
    $(this).find('option:lt(3)').hide();
    //Update chosen
    $(this).chosen().trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/n39fcehh/1/)

As per OP's code

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function () {
    //Get all options
    var options = $(this).find('option');

    //Show all
    options.show();

    //Hide based on condtion
    options.filter(function () {
        return checkedValues.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1;
    });

    //Update chosen
    $(this).chosen().trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. What is chosen-container in the above code?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have some doubt. Is it poosible to iterate through the options? I updated my code.

Comment: But how can i achieve this? because i have many values inside array. If there is only 1 option to hide we can write straight forward code.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole, Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

instead on using on click, use on change e.g.:

```
 jQuery('#element select').on('change',  (function() {

           //your code here

    }));
```